# Import CSV file to be used as an array in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I have a very simple CSV file, with lots of different numerical values.  How can I import this file in to netsuite and save the values in to an array, so that I can use said array in my scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload the file into the file cabinet for retrieval using `nlapiLoadFile(id)` for parsing by scripts.

We use this strategy for processing:

```
 var loadedInvoiceFile = nlapiLoadFile(invoiceFileId); //load the file
 var loadedInvoiceString = loadedInvoiceFile.getValue(); //read its contents
 var invoiceLines = loadedInvoiceString.split('\n'); //split on newlines

 for (var i = 0; i < invoiceLines.length; i++) { //for each line do: 
     var cols = invoiceLines[i].split('\t'); //change delimeter here
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty much exactly what I was looking for.  Question though, will the file type matter on how its processed?  I loaded my CSV file and I believe the problem is in the getValue its giving me a giant string of trash.  Instead of the actual values in the CSV

Comment: Try saving the CSV as a .txt, the extention doesn't matter to the CSV, but NS seems to think CSV = excel and spits it out as binary data (base64 encoded if I recall of the top of my head)

Answer (score 1):

Check the Netsuite File API:

SuiteCloud (Customization, Scripting, and Web Services) : SuiteScript : SuiteScript API : SuiteScript Functions : File APIs

Using this API you can create a file in your Netsuite file cabinet. You can then use the file load API so you can read the contents of the file of the specific item in the file cabinet and create array from it via suitescript.

Answer (score 0):

Do you prefer to use the CSV directly from your scripts?  You could also import the CSV, loading it's values into a "Custom List" in Netsuite -- which can be accessed from scripts as well as forms, etc...